# Terraform looking local vars that are calculated using mapping when using count to create multiple resources

Tags: terraform

I’m using mapped variables in order to create local vars based on longer variable names, I'm using them where we would have abbreviations or where the resource wants a sanitized or shortened version of a value used elsewhere.

Eg

```
variable "env-short" {
  description = "create a shortened version of the name of use in resource naming"
  type        = "map"
  default = {
    "Proof Of Concept"        = "poc"
    "User Acceptance Testing" = "uat"
    "Production"              = "prd"
  }
}
variable "org-short" {
  description = "create a shortened version of the name of use in resource naming"
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
    "My Big Company" = "MBC"
    "My Little Company"    = "MLC"
  }
}
variable "loc-short" {
  description = "create a shortened version of the name of use in resource naming"
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
    "UK South"     = "UKS"
    "UK West"      = "UKW"
    "North Europe" = "NEU"
    "West Europe"  = "WEU"
  }
}
```

And use corresponding variables for their full length mapping equiverlants.

Now I could use as is within a resource block by something like

```
Name = “${lower(“${var.loc-short[$var.location]}”)-${lower(“${var.org-short[$var.organisation]}”)-${lower(“${var.env-short[$var.environment]}”)-myresource”
```

But like all good coders I like to keep things neat and readable by declaring local variables that I can then refer to.

```
locals {
  org-short           = "${lower("${var.org-short["${var.organisation}"]}")}"
  loc-short           = "${lower("${var.loc-short["${var.location}"]}")}"
  env-short           = "${lower("${var.env-short["${var.environment}"]}")}"
  #                      I also create additional for commonly used configurations of them
  name-prefix         = "${lower("${var.org-short["${var.organisation}"]}")}-${lower("${var.loc-short["${var.location}"]}")}"
  name-prefix-storage = "${lower("${var.org-short["${var.organisation}"]}")}${lower("${var.loc-short["${var.location}"]}")}"
}
```

This works really great and keeps things neat tidy and readable.

```
resource "provisioner_example" "test" {
  location   = var.location
  name       = “${local.loc-short}-${local.env-short}-my resource”
```

I would like however to be able to use this format when I start creating multiple resources using the count functionality.

```
resource "provisioner_example" "test" {
  count      = length(var.location)
  location   = var.location[count.index]
  name       = “${local.loc-short[count.index]}-${local.env-short}-my resource”
```

Terraform then complains that the index is invalid in the locals lookup,  varlocation is tuple with 2 elements,| var.loc-short is map of string with 4 elements.  The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: string required.

Now I know I can work around this by  getting rid of the locals variables andincluding the variable calculation directly

```
name =”${lower("${var.loc-short["${var.locations[count.index]}"]}")}-${local.env-short}-my resource"
```

But to me it then makes the code seem more messy and less structured.
Any ideas on how I can pass the count index value to the map lookup?